# Fastest method of finding and replacing row-specific data in a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given an example pandas DataFrame:

```
Index | sometext | a | ff |
    0     'asdff' 'b'  'g' 
    1     'asdff' 'c'  'hh'
    2     'aaf'   'd'  'i'
```

What would be the fastest way to replace all instances of the columns names in the [sometext] field with the data in that column, where the values to replace are row specific?

i.e. the desired result from the above input would be:

```
Index | sometext | a | ff |
    0     'bsdg'  'b'  'g' 
    1     'csdhh' 'c'  'hh'
    2     'ddf'   'd'  'i'
```

note: there is no chance the replacement values would include column names.

I have tried iterating over the rows but the execution time blows out as the length of the DataFrame and number of replacement columns increases.

the [Series.str.replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) method looks at single values as well so would need to be run over each row.

Comment: How about using `.at` to create a small function and then `.apply` to apply the function to the entire data frame?Have you already tried that?

Comment: @user6525564 I haven't tried that - how would you write the apply function?

Comment: @user6525564 the apply function seems to be the saver! I have a an example:

`cols = [col for col in df.columns if col != 'sometext']

def replacer(x):
    for col in cols:
        x['sometext'] = x['sometext'].replace(col, x[col])
    
    return x['sometext']

df['sometext'] = df.apply(replacer, axis=1)`

would you like to write an answer with that so I can select it as correct?

Comment: I was doing something similar.  Looks like you might already have solution but I'll put mine below and can delete if it's not needed.  Btw, I used pythons regex library so it would have that functionality if it matters.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The fastest method I found was to use the apply function in tandem with a replacer function that uses the basic str.replace() method. It's very fast, even with a for loop inside it, and it also allows for a dynamic amount of columns:

```
def value_replacement(df_to_replace, replace_col):
    """ replace the <replace_col> column of a dataframe with the values in all other columns """

    cols = [col for col in df_to_replace.columns if col != replace_col]

    def replacer(rep_df):
        """ function to by used in the apply function """
        for col in cols:
            rep_df[replace_col] = \
                str(rep_df[replace_col]).replace(col.lower(), str(rep_df[col]))

        return rep_df[replace_col]

    df_to_replace[replace_col] = df_to_replace.apply(replacer, axis=1)

    return df_to_replace
```

Answer (score 2):

This way seems quite fast.  See below for a brief discussion.

```
import re

df['new'] = df['sometext']
for v in ['a','ff']:
   df['new'] = df.apply( lambda x: re.sub( v, x[v], x['new']), axis=1 )
```

Results:

```
  sometext  a  ff    new
0    asdff  b   g   bsdg
1    asdff  c  hh  csdhh
2      aaf  d   i    ddf
```

Discussion:

I expanded the sample to 15,000 rows and this was the fastest approach by around 10x or more compared to the existing answers (although I suspect there might be even faster ways).

The fact that you want to use the columns to make row specific substitutions is what complicates this answer (otherwise you would just do a simpler version of @wen's `df.replace`).  As it is, that simple and fast approach requires further code in both my approach and wen's although I think they are more or less working the same way.

Comment: This looks similar to the .replace method, but I'm guessing the re module would have efficiencies that the python str.replace method doesn't - I'll give this a crack and see how it fares! Thanks John!

Comment: @Harlekuin Sure, no problem!  Actually, wen has `regex=True` in his `str.replace` solution so I doubt there is much difference in results but you'd have to dig into pandas source code to really say for sure.

Answer (score 2):

We can do this ..

```
df.apply(lambda x : pd.Series(x['sometext']).replace({'a':x['a'],'ff':x['ff']},regex=True),1)


Out[773]: 
       0
0   bsdg
1  csdhh
2    ddf
```

Comment: I think this is probably the most idiomatic approach although I think it would be even better if the dictionary part could be separated out and looped over as in mine (I briefly tried to do that for your answer but didn't succeed although I expect it should be possible).  Otherwise, I think this and mine are essentially identical but this might be faster depending on what pandas is doing behind the scenes.

Comment: @JohnE Yes, you are right, I feel `apply` is slow , if we want to speed up, maybe `np.vectorize`

Comment: Yeah, I was also thinking some sort of numpy method might be necessary to make this really fast, but that's beyond my ability to do anything quickly

Comment: The number of columns is variable and with different columns each time so the hardcoded dict in the replace method would have to be changed, but I like the idea of using the in-built replace method of the Series object - pandas functions I imagine would work well together - I'll give this a go and see how it goes against the other answers

Answer (score 0):

I have the following:

```
d = {'sometext': ['asdff', 'asdff', 'aaf'], 'a': ['b', 'c', 'd'],  'ff':['g', 'hh', 'i']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

start = timeit.timeit()

def replace_single_string(row_label, original_column, final_column):
    result_1 =  df.get_value(row_label, original_column)
    result_2 = df.get_value(row_label, final_column)
    if 'a' in result_1:
        df.at[row_label, original_column] = result_1.replace('a', result_2)
    else:
        pass
    return df


for i in df.index.values:
    df = replace_single_string(i, 'sometext', 'a')

print df

end = timeit.timeit()
print end - start
```

This ran in 0.000404119491577 seconds in Terminal.

Comment: It's good you timed it but unless you expand the dataset to a few thousand rows all of these answers will be essentially instantaneous.

Comment: Thats true...I agree @JohnE

Comment: btw, if you are using ipython or jupyter, %timeit & %%timeit are really nice for timings

Comment: I use PyCharm, but I wasn't sure what the OP was using and didnt want to complicate things...but i will look into ipython tonight I think....too many people recommending it

Comment: Thanks @neutralCreep, I used something similar to this (i.e. replacing single values at a time) to start with. Unfortunately updating single values runs into performance issues after a lot of rows and columns. I've also noticed a couple of issues with your answer - I assume you meant to use a variable rather than a hard-coded 'a' in the function. Also, the df.get_value method is [deprecated](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.get_value.html) from version 0.21.0 so be careful using that.

Comment: IPython and PyCharm are very different beasts as well - I highly recommend checking it out but it's used for more interactive programming. I usually have my IDE (pycharm etc) running alongside one of the interactive pythons (IPython, Jupyter, nteract etc), so I can test code snippets in isolation to make sure they work before putting it in my project. Definitely give it a go!